# Is there a community about nutrition?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a community about nutrition and diet, from a scientific, health and diet related perspective?
Maybe it is nested in Chemistry or Medical Science.

Comment: Not really but there are sites where specific questions might work. Did you have a specific question in mind, if so maybe you could edit it into the question. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrient-composition/info where there's some information on the kind of questions that do and don't work on one site.

Comment: There's [cooking.se], which covers some, [vegetarianism.se], diet questions are off-topic on medical unless about a specific health-condition, chemistry is fine for digging into raw reactions, [biology.se] is flexible to a certain extent if you want the evolutionary context or biological systems view. It could be a case of mix-and-match, pick your site depending on the question, and fit the question to the site. Try not to cross-post the same question on multiple sites though, take their tours, read their help centres first.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. You are most definitely right about the flexible formulation of specific questions. I guess it can work even though I personally think a consolidated approach for this topic could be a good idea. Just to get some people together and form a community  which can cross reference sources, and transfer knowledge from different areas to form a holistic approach to diet.

Comment: Nutrition is a kind of a "medical science", so possibly also: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @einpoklum https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic < With a disclaimer: Only if it's related to medical conditions, like also listed in the comment above yours.

Comment: Searching [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) for nutrition comes up with [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com).  Area 51 says *"Q&A site for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing health-related needs. Topics include exercise and training, nutrition and diets, wellness, and activities related to strength, endurance, agility, and cardiovascular fitness"*. But, the topics list states that *"nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc."* are off-topic.

Comment: Maybe you could suggest a `Nutrition and Diet` site in Area 51?

Comment: @ChrisRogers you'd need a community first, I believe a few hundred people is regarded as sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

There is no SE site on nutrition and diets. The sites which are loosely connected are very restricted on the nutrition questions you can ask.  For example:

- Medical Sciences **[does not allow](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**

  > questions about nutrition and diet that aren't directly connected to medical treatment
- Physical Fitness **[does not allow](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**

  > nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc.

Maybe you could suggest a `Nutrition and Diet` site on Area 51?  There are a fair few [closed nutrition questions in Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnutrition%5D%20closed%3Ayes) you could tag to the proposed site.

Comment: I will look into the rules and conditions that need to be met to make such request. Thank you for the clear answer. But yeah, at least to me it seems like there would be some interest in the topic.

Comment: If it's related to nutrition for children, it seems to be on-topic at [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrition)